# fer function of indicoio saying Error: could not find function "fer"

Tags: r, image-processing, indico

I installed the indicoio package from

```
devtools::install_github("IndicoDataSolutions/IndicoIo-R")
```

However previous version was also installed. I also tried uninstalling it using

```
remove.packages("indicoio")
```

And reinstalling.

Then when i try to use

```
fer(imageLocation,api_key)
```

with

```
imageLocation = path.expand("~/R/funwithR/data/photoforanalysis.png")
```

I get error saying

```
Error: could not find function "fer"
```

Also

```
library(indicoio)
```

gives

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (content == "") { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (content == "") { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

However

```
image_features(imageLocation,apikey)
```

works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that instead of

```
fer(imageLocation,api_key)
```

which is giving errors.Another function

```
face_emotion(imageLocation,api_key)
```

is working.

"FER is simply our alias function for face_emotion. So neither will be deprecated any time soon.",as said by Chris from indico.

So, the other one seems to be fine.